# PDF rendering issues on IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf, adobe

All, I am working on an ASP.NET 4.6.1 web forms application that renders pdf documents natively on a browser.I get an error message only on **IE 11** when some pdf documents are rendered as shown in the screenshot saying "**The file is damaged and could not be repaired.Local\EWH-6624-0**".The same document renders fine on Chrome and FireFox.Has anyone encountered the same issue? I downloaded the same pdf file in Chrome and tried to open this in **Adobe Reader version 11.0.22**, it gives me the "There was an error opening this document."**The file is damaged and could not be opened**".Please see the screen shots below [image][image]

The asp.net application gets the data from a service and renders it on the UI.This is the C# code that does this

```
var data = getdataAndOtherThingsFromService();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.DocumentStream.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(data.DocumentStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the code below that fixed my issue.This might be helpful to someone in the future

```
var data = getdataAndOtherThingsFromService();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.DocumentStream.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(data.DocumentStream);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

IE isn't rendering the PDF. As the dialog clearly indicates, the Adobe Reader plugin is attempting to render the PDF but is unable to. That's why you get the same dialog when you download the file and open it.

Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, and even PDF files hosted on Dropbox have their own PDF rendering engines built-in and, apparently, are more forgiving of badly formatted PDF than Adobe Reader is.

Unfortunately, you will never be able to create a consistent experience if you rely on the browser, or browser plugins to render your PDF files. Instead, you'll need to implement something like PDF.js which, while not a perfect PDF rendering tool, will at least behave predictably across browsers and operating systems.

Comment: Depending on what your goal is, you could also investigate converting to a format which can be displayed inline on a web page, for example, SVG. Perhaps less predictable for cross browser than PDF.js, but better in terms of user experience (cross browser zooming etc.)

Comment: SVG is not one of the formats that predictably rendering in all browsers when more advanced features are used, and PDFs contain some weird constructs including glyphs/chars display using irregular letter intervals.

Comment: joelgeraci, thanks for your input.I didn't know about PDF.js and that is news to me.I will  make code changes to include PDF.js